# Wait for template to be rendered before action?

Tags: angularjs

I have a large list of items which I navigate to with a button. If I load the data for the list controller immediately, there's a lag while angular builds the list before you see any change to the page. If I instead do a setTimeout in the list controller that waits say, 50ms, the screen changes instantly and the button feels more responsive.

My question is, what is the "proper" way to do this, because I'm pretty sure a setTimeout is a huge hack here.

Edited with Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/VqEiiAFZfV1hoXadw0vf?p=preview

Also, some code from plunkr because stack overflow requires it for some reason:

```
Test.controller('ListController', function($scope) {
  var arr = [];
  for (var i=0; i<5000; i++) {
    arr[i] = i;
  }
  $scope.list = arr
});

Test.controller('ListThatWaitsController', function($scope) {
  var arr = [];
  for (var i=0; i<5000; i++) {
    arr[i] = i;
  }
  setTimeout(function() {
    $scope.list = arr;
    $scope.$apply()
  }, 10);
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'before you see any change to the page)? Can you post a plunker? The behaviour seems wrong to me.

Comment: hard to see how a 50ms delay can make significant visual differences

Comment: The delay isn't what makes the difference. The difference is in whether something happens instantly after you press the button, or after it's actually ready to display.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `resolve` property on your routes (assuming you are using $routeProvider)

```
$routeProvider.when('/myroute', {
  templateUrl: 'view/partial.html',
  resolve: {
    listData: ['service', function (service) {
      return service.getList(); // Returns a promise that resolves with list
    }]
  }
});
```

This way in whatever controller manages your $route, you can inject `listData` and it will be the array you want, but the `$route` won't resolve until the data is ready to go.

Comment: This sounds like the exact opposite of what I require. I need to resolve the route change, and change the template, before the data is available/rendered. Waiting for data before registering change makes a button feel unresponsive.